# Fax to email service?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a fax machine which faxes to phone numbers. I want to use it as a scanner where I get the scanned page as an electronic image

Is there a way to fax to a number and that number/online service forwards the fax as an email attachment?

**Addition:**

Looking for a free service. I will use it like 1-2 times a month so paying seems like an overkill.

Comment: I might also recommend you move this question to superuser.com - as I think most would consider a virtual FAX number to be bit of a stretch to consider it a "web application"

Comment: One other thought: if this is a long term need, you might do better purchasing an inexpensive scanner, which is really the right tool for the job you describe - you should be able to get one for less than $100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAX to Email (and Email to FAX) is a small industry, with many players.
You most certainly can get a "virtual" FAX #, which then results in received FAXes emailed to you as PDF files.

Google for "virtual FAX number" and you will see many vendors providing this service.

I believe most of them will charge some monthly fee, commonly around $10/month.

There may be free ones, with perhaps some limited features.

I recommend you review the various services - and most of them have some type of free trial period - and decide which is the best fit for you.